# The command sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys does not work for me

Tags: ubuntu, debian, gnupg

i tried several fixes i could find for GPG issues, like sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys PUB_KEY, also using the port 80 and even adding manually the pub_key but i still got the same issue! Please help!

> Hit:11 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
> Err:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
> The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key
> is not available: NO_PUBKEY 112695A0E562B32A NO_PUBKEY
> 54404762BBB6E853 Hit:12 http://oem.archive.canonical.com focal
> InRelease Hit:13 http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com focal InRelease
> Reading package lists... Done W: GPG error:
> http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease: The
> following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is
> not available: NO_PUBKEY 112695A0E562B32A NO_PUBKEY 54404762BBB6E853
> E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian-security
> buster/updates InRelease' is not signed. N: Updating from such a
> repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by
> default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user
> configuration details.